# Can't use Shenandoah GC

Tags: java, garbage-collection, shenandoah

I can't put **ShenandoahGC** to work while trying to run a Java application. Regardless of what I try, the output is as follows, when invoking the *java* command from Terminal (or CMD):

> Error occurred during initialization of VM

> Option -XX:+UseShenandoahGC not supported

Running openJDK version 15.0.2 on Ubuntu (WSL) and on Windows, I get the same message on both.

Have tried applying the **-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions** option next to **-XX:+UseShenandoahGC**, but as far as I know the experimental status was dropped with JDK 15.

Comment: are you sure you have not download an oracle jdk and not openjdk? we use openjdk in production, without the `-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions` at all.

Comment: Yep, neither Oracle JDK nor OpenJDK include it. AdoptOpenJDK does.

Comment: yeah, now it all makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I have read here: [What is new in Java 15](https://mkyong.com/java/what-is-new-in-java-15/) (point 10. JEP 379) Shenandoah GC is not included in official OpenJDK 15 release.

Comment: Extracted from item 10 "However, the official OpenJDK 15 build didn’t include the Shenandoah GC (just like what happened in Java 12)." Indeed, this is the reason my runtime didn't find it. AdoptOpenJDK includes it

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is that Oracle Java and the OpenJDK Java builds available from the official OpenJDK download site DO NOT include support for the Shenandoah GC.

But the good news that many other Java 12+ builds do.  AdoptOpenJDK does.  RHEL's Java does.  Ubuntu's Java (installed from the package manager) does.  And I expect others do as well.

---

This situation is explained in an article on Red Hat's blog, excerpted below.

### ["Not all OpenJDK 12 builds include Shenandoah: Here's why"](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2019/04/19/not-all-openjdk-12-builds-include-shenandoah-heres-why)

Dated: April 19, 2019

> [...]
>
> A little history: Shenandoah, a high-performance low-pause-time
> garbage collector, is a Red Hat-led project. When we first proposed to
> contribute Shenandoah to OpenJDK, Oracle made it clear that they
> didn't want to support it. That's fair enough: OpenJDK is free
> software, so you don't have to support anything you don't want. We
> told Oracle that we'd work with them to design a really clean
> pluggable garbage-collector interface that allows anyone easily to
> select the garbage collectors to include in their builds. We did that
> together, and Shenandoah went in to JDK 12.
>
> Evidently Oracle has chosen not to build Shenandoah. They aren't doing
> anything strictly wrong by excluding it, but something doesn't feel
> right to me. These builds aren't supported by Oracle—you need their
> commercial binaries to get support—so why exclude Shenandoah? It might
> simply be that they used their standard build scripts to build their
> open source binaries. However, in a rather feature-light OpenJDK
> release, I find it odd for open source builds to exclude one of the
> most significant contributions. I really appreciate Oracle providing
> GPL-licensed OpenJDK builds, but I wish they'd build all of it.
>
> [...]

Note that the commentary in the above is not mine, but that of the author of the blog posting.

Answer (score 0):

I wish I had an answer for getting a good reliable JVM with Shenandoah enabled, but I've run into similar issues. But just to point out the benefit of Shenandoah.

I'm running a very simple program, but very big. I need between 300-400GB of RAM to run my program. The program is little more than a couple of large array lists and a couple of large ConcurrentHashMaps. I have about 700 million objects that I need to put into those lists and maps. So when I simply measure the load time of this data on any JDK 1.8-1.19 without Shenandoah, ie g1gc, it takes about **40 minutes** and all 32 cores are 90% busy, much of it in the kernel. This is running on Windows Server 2012 R2. By only changing the garbage collector to Shenandoah that time drops to **35 seconds**. With only 1 core busy. That's a huge improvement. The JDK that I found with Shenandoah support was:

```
openjdk version "16.0.2" 2021-07-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-16.0.2+7 (build 16.0.2+7)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-16.0.2+7 (build 16.0.2+7, mixed mode, sharing)
```

The downside is that after loading my data, I populate additional maps of similar size using ForkJoin pools with between 8 and 32 threads and run some RegEx's, but I can repeatedly crash the JVM. I don't know if this is due to something I've done wrong, the fork join pools, garbage collector, or the OpenJDK. But I'd love to find a production hardened JDK with Shenandoah.

Comment: Whatever bug I stumbled onto is not limited to the OpenJDK, but I can recreate it, or at least crash the jvm, using the Azul JDK as well. Both on Windows.  
    
    openjdk 19.0.1 2022-10-18
    OpenJDK Runtime Environment Zulu19.30+11-CA (build 19.0.1+10)
    OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Zulu19.30+11-CA (build 19.0.1+10, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This doesn't feel very much like an answer but letting someone know that your problem is a hard problem can be important. I think this has a chance to help someone, so I'm going to leave it up.

Comment: I'm afraid that this is not a good answer.  1) It doesn't answer the question.  2) It actually contains a warning about a problem ... but the warning is not really *actionable*, since the limited information provide is not sufficient to characterize the problem.  A better idea would be to post the problem as a Question, including relevant code and other evidence as a [minimal reproducible example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example).   You could also submit a bug report to the supplier of your JVM ... though they will probably need a way to reproduce the bug too.