# To use Shenandoah GC in Oracle JDK 16

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, shenandoah

I recently came across Shenandoah GC while working on JVM memory settings. Tried to use in one of our applications with Oracle jdk 16 version and got below error-

*Unrecognized VM option 'UseShenandoahGC'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.*

*$ java -version
java version "16.0.1" 2021-04-20
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 16.0.1+9-24)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 16.0.1+9-24, mixed mode, sharing)*

But I read online that Shenandoah GC works with jdk 13 onwards by default and with jdk 12 by using unlock experimental vm options JVM flag.

Linux version-
*NAME="Oracle Linux Server"
VERSION="7.4"*

Tried this with Oracle jdk version 1.8.251 also. I am not an expert in JVM so please help me if I am missing something. What could be the issue here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't use Shenandoah GC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66333767/cant-use-shenandoah-gc)

Comment: Yes. Thanks for that. So any idea in which Oracle jdk version, I can try Shenandoah GC??

Comment: No Oracle JDK comes with Shenandoah GC. Oracle deliberately [disables](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8215030) Shenandoah GC in their builds, because they develop a competitive solution - ZGC. If you want to run Shenandoah, try OpenJDK builds from other vendors - Liberica JDK, AdoptOpenJDK etc.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Will try that.